Set Link to Table Row in Confluence
Problem:
I am trying to set a Link to a table row in confluence.
Attempted solution
I tried the Anchor macro to a table cell. I could create the anchor macro correctly
When I link to the Anchor macro (e.g. with ctrl-K) on a different confluence page, a link is added. When I click on the link it leads to the beginning of the Page where I created the anchor.
I expected a link to the table row on the page not the beginning of the page.
